# I am trying to install node in my windows PC

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install node in my windows PC.. I am getting the following error

```
PS C:\Users\emarian\Desktop\JS Projects\javascript-essential-training-2832077-main> npm install
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It worked the first time I installed it, I'm not sure whats happening...

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling nodejs and make sure you're runing stable version of it.
Link:- https://nodejs.org/en/

Or

Check if you have installed it properly by running this two commands in cmd.

```
node --verison
npm -version
```

[image]